# Is it possible to concurrently run commands in cloud-init

Tags: cloud-init

As part of my cloud-init, I need to download a large file (ie. a 6GB toolchain / SDK). This step is executed through `runcmd` and takes 3-5 minutes, which is about half of the time of the initialization process.

Is it possible to at least start the download in the background earlier (ie, as part of `bootcmd`) and proceed with the rest of initialization (ie, `apt-get install ...`)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is certainly possible. E.g., given the following cloud-config:

```
#cloud-config
bootcmd:
 - echo 'Starting foreground sleep' >> /var/tmp/log
 - date +%s >> /var/tmp/log
 - sleep 5
 - date +%s >> /var/tmp/log

 - echo 'Starting background sleep' >> /var/tmp/log
 - date +%s >> /var/tmp/log
 - sleep 10 &
 - date +%s >> /var/tmp/log
```

I get this kind of result:

```
cat /var/tmp/log
Starting foreground sleep
1613538543
1613538548
Starting background sleep
1613538548
1613538548
```

Increasing the background sleep has no effect on the amount of time it takes cloud-init to finish. A background `wget` should work similarly.

That said, this isn't really what `bootcmd` was designed for. If you check the [cloud-init docs](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html?highlight=bootcmd#bootcmd), it specifies that `bootcmd should only be used for things that could not be done later in the boot process`. Some fairly major setup tasks (including disk setup) can still happen after `bootcmd` runs, so starting some large downloads that early during boot may not be a wise choice.

The `runcmd` module should run before any of the apt installs. You can verify with `cloud-init analyze show` on your cloud instance. Unless you have a really good reason to use `bootcmd`, you should probably just stick with `runcmd`.